# Android, MediaPlayer, PrepareAsync и Стрим интернет радио

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

```
final String DATA_STREAM = "http://online.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_128";

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(DATA_STREAM);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "prepareAsync");
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Вот кусочек злополучного рабочего(!) кода с которым дерусь до сих пор. У меня на дебаге и релизы работают на ура, на 100500 эмулированных устройствах работает тоже нормально, но скачал приложение другу на Galaxy tab 3 под управлением дроида 4.4.2 обнаружился очень неприятный баг: нажимаю кнопку play качинается кеширование, потом воспроизводится примерно на секунду, заново кешируется и уже нормально воспроизводится. С чем это связанно и как оно лечится?